# Generate private SEQUENCE for each PARTITION

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of match ups in different games, and I would like to calculate how dense the matchup space in regards to each game is. Example table:

```
id | game  | start_dt
---+-------+-----------------
1  | dota2 | 2020-01-01 15:00
---+-------+-----------------
2  | dota2 | 2020-01-01 15:05
---+-------+-----------------
3  | dota2 | 2020-01-01 18:00
---+-------+-----------------
4  | cs-go | 2020-01-01 13:05
---+-------+-----------------
5  | cs-go | 2020-01-01 13:15
---+-------+-----------------
6  | dota2 | 2020-01-01 12:00
---+-------+-----------------
7  | cs-go | 2020-01-01 14:45
```

Would **ideally** yield:

```
id | game  | start_dt        |  time_group_id
---+-------+-----------------+---------------
6  | dota2 | 2020-01-01 12:00| 1
---+-------+-----------------+---------------
1  | dota2 | 2020-01-01 15:00| 2
---+-------+-----------------+---------------
2  | dota2 | 2020-01-01 15:05| 2
---+-------+-----------------+---------------
3  | dota2 | 2020-01-01 18:00| 3
---+-------+-----------------+---------------
4  | cs-go | 2020-01-01 13:05| 4
---+-------+-----------------+---------------
5  | cs-go | 2020-01-01 13:15| 4
---+-------+-----------------+---------------
7  | cs-go | 2020-01-01 14:45| 5
```

Which basically means, that if a gap between the next game and the previous one is less or equal to 10 minutes, they are considered in the same time group. Else they are different time groups and it proceeds.

Those `time_group_id`s are then used to map useful information about matches and their time frequency.

My code is below, and it serves the purpose ideally, however, it doesn't give evenly spaced ids, so I have to use a composite of game `VARCHAR` and group_id for the field to uniquely represent a group. Please, run it in the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9cacb9db934e7fc13197c1c22b9cf5f8) to understand, what I mean.

```
CREATE TABLE fight(
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   game VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO fight(date, game) 
VALUES 
('2020-01-01 15:00'::TIMESTAMP, 'dota2'), 
('2020-01-01 15:05'::TIMESTAMP, 'dota2'), 
('2020-01-01 18:00'::TIMESTAMP, 'dota2'), 
('2020-01-01 13:05'::TIMESTAMP, 'cs-go'), 
('2020-01-01 13:15'::TIMESTAMP, 'cs-go'),
('2020-01-01 12:00'::TIMESTAMP, 'dota2'),
('2020-01-01 14:45'::TIMESTAMP, 'cs-go');

SELECT * FROM fight;

CREATE SEQUENCE seq START 1 CACHE 1;

SELECT
a.id,
a.game,
a.start_dt,
(CASE WHEN (a.start_dt - INTERVAL '10 min' <= a.prev_start_dt) THEN currval('seq')
     ELSE nextval('seq')
END)::VARCHAR || '|' || a.game AS time_group_id
FROM
(
SELECT 
   fight.id, 
   fight.game,
   fight.date AS start_dt,
   LAG (fight.date, 1, fight.date) OVER (PARTITION BY fight.game ORDER BY fight.date) AS prev_start_dt
FROM fight CROSS JOIN (SELECT setval('seq', 1)) s
) a
ORDER BY a.game, a.start_dt;
```

The question is: is there **the ideal** way to do this, or should I stick with what I got?

Comment: Your code looks OK. But why do you want to store that information? You can easily compute it on the fly when needed.

Comment: Thanks for asking. This is mainly because there is a need to map a large amount of information stored in another table to each group of events. For example, there is 100 records for the first event and 200 records for the second one and so on, and this query would connect those records into one group, if those events are close in terms of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a sequence for this, just a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT f.*,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE prev_date < date - interval '10 min') OVER (ORDER BY date) as time_group_id
FROM (SELECT f.*,
             LAG(f.date) OVER (PARTITION BY f.game ORDER BY f.date) AS prev_date
      FROM fight f
     ) f;
```

Notes:  This might start at `0` rather than `1`.  If that makes a difference, use `1 +`.

This produces a number, not a string.  You can convert to a string (using `::text`) if that is what you really need.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1c9ad667cce2beb89d1ae85f0a61622c) is a db<>fiddle

Comment: But the meaning of the query is to divide Fights in groups such that the current Fight is no later than 10 minutes than the previous one AND to give each of those group a unique id based on both the first condition and by their game. I couldn't run your query, and I really cannot get what you were trying to get across. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @winwin . . . I fixed the query and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much, thanks to your idea with the cumulative sum I was able to solve this problem the way it was intended! I'll post the answer, I really would like you to see what I was trying to achieve. You're a cool guy, thanks, I'll give you all the thumbs up ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
b.id,
b.game,
b.start_dt,
sum(b.time_group_count) OVER (ORDER BY b.game, b.start_dt) as time_group_id
FROM
(SELECT
a.id,
a.game,
a.start_dt,
CASE WHEN a.prev_start_dt IS NULL THEN 1
     WHEN (a.start_dt - INTERVAL '10 min' <= a.prev_start_dt) THEN 0
     ELSE 1
END AS time_group_count
FROM
(
SELECT 
   fight.id, 
   fight.game,
   fight.date AS start_dt,
   LAG (fight.date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fight.game ORDER BY fight.date) AS prev_start_dt
FROM fight 
) a
ORDER BY a.game, a.start_dt) b;
```

This query is what gave me the results I really wanted. Really grateful to the cumsum idea by @Gordon Linoff, thank you!